# Microsoft WebView2 push services

Tags: c#, webview, push-notification, webview2, domexception

I have a C# desktop application with MS webview2. In a website that im trying to open gives me this error. ( this is a inspect console error)

An error occurred while retrieving token. DOMException: Registration failed - push service error

anyone know how to solve this issue?

I tried pyview, pyqt5, cefsharp, electron.. every webview gives me this error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Notification API in WebView2 is still experimental.

See:

https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/308

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/release-notes?tabs=win32cpp#101988-prerelease